# Can hackers impact information inside state?

Tags: reactjs, security, state

in my react application I calculate the price of the order in the back-end, and then transfer it to the state. But at the end, the paypal order amount is passed through the state. Which means, if a hacker can find a way to change the state to "$1", they can get the items cheaper.

This is just one case of me calculating stuff inside my state, and I was wondering if a scenario of hacker changing the state is possible.

**One more case of me doing sensitive stuff with state** :
When a user tries to reset password and their ip is not blacklisted for too many tries, I transfer them to a page where they need to enter the pin-code that they received to their phone. If they enter invalid pin I increase the "failedTries" state and won't accept their submission if they have failed 3 times. This is done instead of going all the way to the db and storing their failed pin codes. If a hacker changes the state to 0, they can simply brute force the phone pin which is only 6 digit long.

Comment: If you're relying on the client to tell you what the price should be, whether or not they change it in the *state* is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I get the item price from the DB, but if they increase the quantity of the same item to 2, I am not going to the DB again. I am just changing the state of total price to itemprice * 2.

Comment: @Theprocodernotreallyxd: Updating the display of prices client-side based on already known information (such as re-calculating based on quantity) is certainly reasonable.  But that information is entirely for the user experience.  When the actual transaction takes place, you should be controlling the price server-side.  This doesn't really have anything to do with React or how it manages state.  All client-side frameworks are client-side.  Never rely on data coming from the client, always validate it server-side.

Comment: Your other example is also a problem. I really hope by *"instead of going all the way to the db"* you don't mean that the client is told what the right PIN is, because that's wildly insecure. **Do not** rely on client state for things that actually matter. By all means reflect the logic the server will apply so you can give a good user experience, but that "three strikes and you're out" rule needs to be applied somewhere that **you control**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe they client is not told what the right pin is. But I'm not adding to the document a failedLogin value. I'll do that now if that's insecure.
As for the pricing, when using paypal's API you eventually need to pass the price to the front end in order to render the right button. Is there anything to do about that?

Comment: @Theprocodernotreallyxd: Admittedly I haven't used the PayPal API, but if the flow involves directing the user to PayPal with transaction data then I would imagine PayPal itself needs to contact your server with some kind of token to validate the information, no?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should save failedTries in database not in UI part, as calculated price.

You should get the protected content from a server, and this server should only deliver the content when the user sends a valid token.

This way, yes, anyone can flip the switch in the client, but that only shows the UI components, without any data.

This is the usual approach when creating single-page applications. As long as you don't have secret or sensitive data right in your client from the beginning, they are as safe as your server / API that delivers the data.

Comment: As for the pricing, when using paypal's API you eventually need to pass the price to the front end in order to render the right button. And eventually I do need to give the button a price from the state, even if the information comes from the DB. Is there anything to do about that? is it safe?